How to trigger Azure Logic App when a file is not being uploaded in Blob Storage? When you have replacing previous file?
I have one blob storage , in that am updating every 15 min new files .
Now i have to configre the mail notification when new file is uploaded or not .
The main problem is the blob is not empty when new file is not uploaded.
Now i have confirge the mail notification when new file is uploaded or not using logic app .
How should i do ?
I have to configure the mail notification using azure logic appps.


Now i have to configre the mail notification when new file is uploaded or not .

You can use below design to get email when the last modified date is more than 15 minutes :

Clearly:
List Blobs and then initialize an integer variable with 0.

Then take the last modified:
add(div(sub(ticks(dateDifference(items('For_each')?['LastModified'],utcNow())), ticks('00:00:00')), 600000000), div(mod(ticks(dateDifference(items('For_each')?['LastModified'],utcNow())), 600000000), 600000000000.0))

is less than 15 minutes then increment the variable:

Then:

Output:



Thanks for your quick revert , I will try this. Thank you so much ,

using this flow I can achieve also mail notification when new file is uploaded?

For that you need to use When a new blob added or modified trigger

SO i have to use two different workflows ?

to upload new file
2.if file is not uploaded


Yes , and AFAIk there is no other way to trigger when uploaded or when not uploaded

Thank you @RithwikBojja am satisfied with your answers , really you helped me a lot

Gald that you are satisified @Rohit
